# Cannot style hbox or vbox

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, hbox

Quite frustrating as I follow guidelines and basic tutorial. I can apply CSS styles to differnt elements but not to vbox or hbox.

I have the following simple Apps creating a simple scene using a FMXL and CSS:

```
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class BingRen extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parent root = null;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL xmlUrl = getClass().getResource("/BingRen.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(xmlUrl);
        try {
            root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("BingRen.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

With FXML, creating just a BordPane and 2 HBox containing one label each. Almost as simple as HellopApp :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>


<BorderPane fx:id="rootBorderPane"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="MainControler">
    <top>
        <HBox>
            <Label text="BingRen app" />
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <bottom>
        <HBox>
            <Label text="Status bar" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
    <center>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

And CSS to set some basic properties:

```
.hbox {
    -fx-background-color: #00ff00;
    -fx-border-color: #00ff00;
    -fx-border-width: 2px;
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-spacing: 8;
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: #0000ff;
}
```

Label properly turn blue but not of the hbox style are applied

---

In fact none of the suggestion worked.

I tried :

- Change .hbox to .Hbox in css file
- Make a #allbox in css file and add fx-id="allbox" and fxml file

For every change, I change the color for label to ensure the new version of css is read through.

Label always change color but I never get backgroung or paddings in the Hboxes

Answer (score 6):

**Why your current approach fails**

Look at the [CSS documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

For [HBox](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#hbox)

> Style class: empty by default

For [Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76250960/cannot-style-hbox-or-vbox)

> Style class: label

So there is no such style class as ".hbox" for a HBox unless you add one, which you have not done.

**Background on CSS selectors and JavaFX**

Read the section titled ["CSS and the JavaFX Scene Graph"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph):

> CSS selectors are used to match styles to scene‑graph nodes. The
> relationship of a Node to a CSS selector is as follows:
>
> - Node's getTypeSelector method returns a String which is analogous to a
>   CSS Type Selector. By default, this method returns the simple name of
>   the class. Note that the simple name of an inner class or of an
>   anonymous class may not be usable as a type selector. In such a case,
>   this method should be overridden to return a meaningful value.
> - Each
>   node in the scene‑graph has a styleClass property. Note that a node
>   may have more than one style‑class. A Node's styleClass is analogous
>   to the class="..." attribute that can appear on HTML elements. See
>   Class Selectors.
> - Each node in the scene‑graph has an id variable, a
>   string. This is analogous to the id="..." attribute that can appear
>   HTML elements. See ID Selectors.

**Application examples**

So there are three ways you can fix this:

1. Use a **type selector** in your CSS file:

   ```
   HBox { <css rules> }
   ```
2. Apply a **style class** in your CSS file:

   ```
   .my-hbox-styleclass { <css rules> }
   ```

   And in FXML write:

   ```
   <HBox styleClass="my-hbox-styleclass">
   ```

   OR in code write:

   ```
   myHBox.getStyleClass().add("my-hbox-styleclass");
   ```
3. Apply a **style id** in your CSS file:

   ```
   #my-hbox-id { <css rules> }
   ```

   And in FXML write:

   ```
   <HBox id="my-hbox-id">
   ```

   OR in code write:

   ```
   myHBox.setId("my-hbox-id");
   ```

**Selector scope differences**

There are differences in the meaning for the standard application of each approach:

1. The **type selector** will apply to all HBox types in your UI.
2. The **class selector** will apply to anything which has the given style class applied.
3. The **id selector** is usually used for a single node in the UI, rather than a type or class of node.  It should be unique within an FXML document or scene graph tree, though this is not enforced.